# Which weapon is better? Is it the Scythe or The giant Spoon of Doom?

Tags: candy-box-2

In *Candy Box 2*, which weapon is better? Is it the Scythe or A giant Spoon / The giant Spoon of Doom.

Every time I test them, they seem to both do the same thing. When I use A giant Spoon, it 1 shots the octopus king in like 1 or 2 seconds. And then when I use the Scythe, it kills it really fast in like 1 or 2 seconds too.

Answer (score 2):

> The Giant Spoon of Doom is the most powerful melee weapon in the game. It does 315 damage but its speed is "incredibly slow". Nevertheless it has the best DPS of all weapons, coming out slightly ahead of the Scythe. It is the enchanted version of the Giant Spoon.

[Source](http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Giant_Spoon_of_Doom)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you do the math, the Giant spoon of doom has a DPS of 211, while the scythe has a DPS of 220. Therefore, the scythe is the superior weapon.